# Как добавить карту гугл без интерфейса и с подписью под маркером

Tags: javascript, html, google-maps-api

Вообщем, мне нужно на сайт добавить гугл карту[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Как вы видите на скрине, на карте не должно быть элементов управления, а также рядом с маркером должна быть подпись.
Проблема в том, что если я добавляю через АПИ, я не могу установить текст рядом с маркером.
Вот мой код:

```
 var map;
         function initMap() {
           map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementsByClassName('map')[0], {
             center: {lat: 55.800115, lng: 37.715050},
             zoom: 18,
             disableDefaultUI: true
           });
           var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
               position: {lat: 55.800115, lng: 37.715050},
               map: map
             });

         }
```

Если же я воспользуюсь гугл сервисом и вставлю карту айфрамом, то я не могу убрать элементы управления.
Может кто то знает что делать??

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Вам нужен будет API Key для гугл карты и тогда вы сможете добавить гугл карту на сайт, ну и используйте код, там добавляэтся кастомный маркер и Label

Склонируйте себе с гита либо скачайте архив и посмотрите на реальном примере  [вот ссылка](https://github.com/YuriyChaban/itaskinbeauty.git)

```js
try {
    var point = {
        lat: 55.800115,
        lng: 37.715050
    };
    var markerSize = {
        x: 46,
        y: 49
    };
    google.maps.Marker.prototype.setLabel = function(label) {
        this.label = new MarkerLabel({
            map: this.map,
            marker: this,
            text: label
        });
        this.label.bindTo('position', this, 'position');
    };
    var MarkerLabel = function(options) {
        this.setValues(options);
        this.span = document.createElement('span');
        this.span.className = 'map-marker-label';
    };
    MarkerLabel.prototype = $.extend(new google.maps.OverlayView(), {
        onAdd: function() {
            this.getPanes().overlayImage.appendChild(this.span);
            var self = this;
            this.listeners = [
                google.maps.event.addListener(this, 'position_changed', function() {
                    self.draw();
                })
            ];
        },
        draw: function() {
            var text = String(this.get('text'));
            var position = this.getProjection().fromLatLngToDivPixel(this.get('position'));
            this.span.innerHTML = text;
            this.span.style.left = (position.x - (markerSize.x / 2)) - (text.length * 3) - 46 + 'px';
            this.span.style.top = (position.y - markerSize.y - 49) + 'px';
        }
    });
    function initialize() {
        var myLatLng = new google.maps.LatLng(point.lat, point.lng);
        var gmap = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('mapWrapper'), {
            zoom: 18,
            center: myLatLng,
            zoomControl: true,
            disableDoubleClickZoom: true,
            mapTypeControl: true,
            scaleControl: true,
            scrollwheel: true,
            panControl: true,
            streetViewControl: true,
            draggable : true,
            overviewMapControl: true,
            mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP,
            styles: [
               {
                    "elementType": "labels.icon"
                }
            ]
        });
        var myMarker = new google.maps.Marker({
            map: gmap,
            icon: "../images/site-map-logo.png",
            position: myLatLng,
            label: 'Enter here your label text',
            draggable: false
        });
        google.maps.event.addListener(myMarker, 'click', function() {
            window.open("https://www.google.com.ua/maps/place/Krasnoarmeyskaya+ul.,+89,+Moskva,+Russia,+125319/@55.8036713,37.5346202,20.75z/data=!4m5!3m4!1s0x46b549c60271b8a5:0x2e7f6efb37ae7a40!8m2!3d55.8036976!4d37.5346816?hl=en");
        });
    }
    google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, "load", initialize);
} catch (e) {
    alert(e);
}
```

```css
.mapWrapper {
  overflow: hidden;
  padding-bottom: 56%;
  position: relative;
  height: 0;
}

.mapWrapper iframe {
  left: 0;
  top: 0;
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  position: absolute;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<!-- google API key for map -->
 <script type="text/javascript" src="http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?v=3&amp;sensor=false"></script>
<div id='mapWrapper'></div>
```