# Как сделать HTML маркер в Google map?

Tags: javascript, html, google-maps-api

Есть маркер, который нужно поместить на гугл карту ,и при клике на который должны разворачиваться 2 блока и карусель с изображениями. Посмотреть на него в действии можно здесь - [Пример маркера](https://codepen.io/jSas/pen/VWRPNE)

Вопрос: Как вместо маркера задать html элемент, и как повешать на него событие `onClick`?

Answer (score 1):

Вот помотрите [тут](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/692979/%D0%9A%D0%B0%D0%BA-%D0%B4%D0%BE%D0%B1%D0%B0%D0%B2%D0%B8%D1%82%D1%8C-%D0%BA%D0%B0%D1%80%D1%82%D1%83-%D0%B3%D1%83%D0%B3%D0%BB-%D0%B1%D0%B5%D0%B7-%D0%B8%D0%BD%D1%82%D0%B5%D1%80%D1%84%D0%B5%D0%B9%D1%81%D0%B0-%D0%B8-%D1%81-%D0%BF%D0%BE%D0%B4%D0%BF%D0%B8%D1%81%D1%8C%D1%8E-%D0%BF%D0%BE%D0%B4-%D0%BC%D0%B0%D1%80%D0%BA%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%BC/692987#692987), в примере используэтся маркер, при клике на который будер переход на google maps, либо можно навешать свою функцию

```
google.maps.event.addListener(myMarker, 'click', function() {
        window.open("https://www.google.com.ua/maps/place/Krasnoarmeyskaya+ul.,+89,+Moskva,+Russia,+125319/@55.8036713,37.5346202,20.75z/data=!4m5!3m4!1s0x46b549c60271b8a5:0x2e7f6efb37ae7a40!8m2!3d55.8036976!4d37.5346816?hl=en");
    });
```

сюда, вместо window.open нужно добавить ваш вызов функии